# How to use a conditional statment inside a vue.js :attr

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a input field that defines max and min on the input, but somethimes the max are set to 0 and the max should be disabled or set to 150 (or some high number.)

What would be the best way to make a conditional statement to check this. So far this is my code:

```
<input v-model="age" :min="10" :max="0">
```

I tested with:

```
<input v-model="age" :min="10" :max="age.max ? 0 : 130">
```

But problem here is that if maxage is 40, the value is set to 0.

Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Off-topic comment: max value should be higher than the min

Comment: Yes, but if max is 0, the max needs to be 100 or not show :max at all.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're expecting `max` to be, but maybe this is what you want: `:max="age.max ? age.max : 130"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use a computed property for this.

```
<input v-model="age" :min="0" :max="maxValue" />

// in you computed key:
maxValue() {
  let max;
  /* add any logic according to your needs */

  return max; // returns 0, 1, 10, 254, ... or null, undefined, ...
}
```